# CA-sv will supported in Java 8?

Tags: java, mocking, java-8, ca-lisa, service-virtualization

CA service virtualization can be configured by Java 8
As I checked with CA sv document I had seen its supports only limited Java versions.
Kindly help me to get info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as running DevTest Server and DevTest Workstation are concerned, the Windows installer automatically includes a compatible JDK.  As of the latest GA release (10.1.0), that would be Java 8.  Most recent releases have been Java 8.

On Unix, you must provide your own JVM, and there are different settings for Oracle and IBM JVMs.

https://docops.ca.com/devtest-solutions/10-1/en/installing/preinstallation/system-requirements#SystemRequirements-SupplyingYourOwnJVM

That link is specific to 10.1.0 which requires Java 8.  If you have an older version, please check the version specific documentation.

Note that OpenJRE is ***not*** supported at any version.

The JDK that DevTest runs on is only important if you're writing custom extensions.  You don't want to build an extension with a Java version newer than what the server uses.

Scripts within a VSM, however, are another matter.  The deprecated JavaScript step, I believe, only understands JDK 1.4.  I'm not certain about the JSR-223 step but, if you select Beanshell, you're probably still limited to 1.4.

You're also limited to JDK 1.4 in Beanshell expressions like:

```
{{=new java.util.Date();}}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Mike. Got it.